# Understanding CSRF vulnerability in Web Application?

Tags: web-application, csrf

I want to understand what is CSRF vulnerability. I use authorization system in my web application and found CSRF.

What should we do to solve it?

Actually I want to create simulation for this vulnerability but I don't understand perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that you read the OWASP references on this topic, including:

- [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)
- [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
- [Testing for CSRF (OWASP-SM-005)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSRF_%28OWASP-SM-005%29)
- [Reviewing code for Cross-Site Request Forgery issues](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_code_for_Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_issues)

as well as the following resources:

- [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 5: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-5.html)
- [OWASP Top 10 Deeper Dive – A5: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/owasp-csrf/)

In general, if you have questions about web security and secure web development, a good starting point is to look at what resources OWASP has available.